# silverlight 5: force grid being in sync before screen-capture via writeablebitmap

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, redraw, writeablebitmap

**In silverlight 5:** I have built a product configurator that also constructs a drawing via combination of image's and Rectangle,Ellipse,Polygon constructions.

The configurator works fine and the drawing is fine as well. When a product is ready it's placed in a gallery (List box) and a thumbnail of the drawing is showing along with some main information. So far so good.

I can also save the configurations that are placed in the gallery to disc (xml) and load them later on to continue and finish. Here is the problem. I read the products one by one to the configurator, all business rules are in place then and the drawing takes place. But at the moment I save the product to the gallery the snapshot of the drawing stays blank.

I'm sure that all steps are fine because when I break at the point before placing the product in gallery, the drawing is showing correct. However, in the gallery the drawing is blank. So I assume a sync/timing/update problem but can't find a way to force redrawing of the grid that contains the images and drawings.

### In axml, the listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbTiles" Loaded="lbTiles_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="2,2,0,0" Height="233" Width="892" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Background="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF606060">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate >
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Gainsboro">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#4F000000" >
              <Grid >
                 <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{Binding mImage, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="110" ></Image>
              </Grid>
              </Border>
                <TextBox  TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120" Height="23" Text="{Binding mName, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" FontSize="11" />
                <TextBox  TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120" Height="23" Text="{Binding mPrice, Mode=OneWay}" IsTabStop="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" FontSize="11" />
                 <TextBox  TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120" Height="23" Text="{Binding mTotal, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" FontSize="11" />
                  <TextBox  TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120" Height="23" Text="{Binding mFreight, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" FontSize="11" />
                  </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
```

### The grid:

```
 <Grid Name="myDrawing" Background="Gainsboro" Height="437" Width="486">
    <Rectangle Name="clrFrame" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="27,5,32,5" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" ></Rectangle>
       <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
       <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Rectangle Name="clrWindow_1" Visibility="Collapsed" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" ></Rectangle>
         <Rectangle Name="clrWindow_2" Visibility="Collapsed" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" ></Rectangle>
         <Rectangle Name="clrWindow_3" Visibility="Collapsed" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" ></Rectangle>
         <Ellipse Name="clrWindow_4" Visibility="Collapsed" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
          <Polygon Name="clrWindow_5" Visibility="Collapsed" StrokeThickness="18" IsHitTestVisible="False"></Polygon>
          <Rectangle Name="clrDoor" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="136,196,162,122" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" ></Rectangle>
          <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
          <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
          <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
          <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
           <Image Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.5,4,0,0" Name="imDrawingL6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
      </Grid>
```

**C# Code**

```
for( int i = 0; i < count i++ )
{
xmlread al values to currentCasingComposition.....

writeToScreen(); // apply businessrules and do the drawing
myDrawing.InvalidateMeasure();
myDrawing.InvalidateArrange();
myDrawing.UpdateLayout();
// an exit here leaves me with the product in de confugurator and the drawing is fine
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(myDrawing, null); // capture drawing
currentCasingComposition.mImage = bmp;
currentCasingComposition.mImage.Invalidate();
currentCasingComposition.calculatePrice();
    ocCasingCompositions.Add(currentCasingComposition); to gallery via ObservableCollection
}
```

Who knows the solution?

BR, Ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateLayout() is asynchronous on the UI thread, so you should wait for it to complete before calling the rest of the block. Unfortunately, I can find nothing on how to get notified when UpdateLayout() completes. All the examples that refer to it use a DispatcherTimer to wait a second or so before carrying on. So what I would do is create a one-off dispatcher timer, set its interval to 1000 milliseconds (or less, as needed) , and execute the rest of your code on it Tick event.

Comment: Hello Boluc,Tx for your quick response!

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have put that Invalidate and Update code lines only as an attempt to force the update of the ui. What I would need in this case is sync behaviour rather then async. Now I would have to wait untill the Tick event has occured before continuing with the next product-item. Otherwise I would overwrite the previous data. I've tried to use a simple for loop, but that does not the trick, most likely because at that moment the code is not handeld multi tasking. My loop keeps the processor occupied and the screen update does not happen.

Comment: HOLY COW! Man your a genius.. you saved my bacon today!